# activity indicator not hiding when webpage has loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

In xCode I've put in both the activity indicator and UIWebView aspects, however the activity indicator will not hide after the webpage has loaded. Here's the code, any tips for how I can get this to work?

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Videoview.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate;
        loadAdress()
    }
    func loadAdress()  {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
        Videoview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_  : UIWebView)  {
        ActvityView.startAnimating()
        NSLog("The webview is started loading")
    }
    func webViewDidStopLoad(_  : UIWebView)  {
        ActvityView.stopAnimating()
        ActvityView.isHidden=true;
        NSLog("The webview is done loading")

    }
    func WebViewActvityStopError(_ : UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error){
        ActvityView.stopAnimating()
        ActvityView.isHidden=true;
        print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You are missing out webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not use `UIWebView` it is deprecated. Instead of `UIWebView` use `WKWebView`

To stop `UIActivityIndicator` use `WKWebView` delegate method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
       // Hide activity indicator here
     }
}
```

You need to follow this link : [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, however unfortunately after adding that and changing the UIWebView to WKWebView it doesn't seem to have any affect on the indicator. I would send through the updated code however it won't seem to format properly through stackoverflow. Do you know if there is anything else that could have some effect on the code? Thanks for your assistance in any regard :)

Comment: implementing WKWebView is similar to implementing UIWebView. I will update my answer.